# Stop Azure Function from excessive logging to Application Insights

Tags: azure, logging, azure-functions, azure-application-insights

I have an Azure Function written in Java that is accompanied with following `host.json` file:

```
{
    "version": "2.0",
    "extensionBundle": {
        "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
        "version": "[3.*, 4.0.0)"
    },
    "extensions": {
        "http": {
            "routePrefix": ""
        },
        "queues": {
            "maxPollingInterval": "00:00:10"
        }
    },
    "logging": {
        "logLevel": {
            "default": "Warning",
            "Host": "Warning",
            "Function": "Warning",
            "Azure.Core": "Error"
        }
    }
}
```

In my understanding setting the `"default": "Warning"` log level should result in producing very little logs, except for situations when something unusual happens. Unfortunately this does not seem to be the case. In Application Insights I can see tons of log entries like for example:

- "WorkerStatusRequest completed"
- "Worker initialized"
- "Worker terminate request received. Gracefully shutting down the worker."
- "Function "abc" (Id: defghijk) invoked by Java Worker"
- "Executed 'Functions.abc' (Succeeded, Id=defghijk, Duration=826ms)"
- "FunctionLoadRequest received by the Java worker, Java version - C:\Program Files\Java\microsoft-jdk-11.0.16.1 - 11.0.16.1"
- ...

My question is how to make it silent. Those log statements are not so interesting for me. I have also observed that they are all logged with `SeverityLevel=1` which according to the docs is equal to `Debug`.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Try making all possible options to false under [Application insights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-host-json#applicationinsights)

```
{
    "version":"2.0",
    "logging":{
        "logLevel":{
            "default":"Information",
            "Function":"Information",
            "Host.Aggregator":"Information",
            "Host":"Error"
        },
        "applicationInsights":{
            "enableDependencyTracking":false,
            "excludedTypes":"Request; Dependency:"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

***Modify your host.json as shown below to reduce the excessive logging:***

```json
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "extensionBundle": {
      "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
      "version": "[3.*, 4.0.0)"
  },
  "extensions": {
      "http": {
          "routePrefix": ""
      },
      "queues": {
          "maxPollingInterval": "00:00:10"
      }
  },
    "logging": {
      "logLevel": {
        "default": "Warning",
        "Function": "Error",
        "Host.Aggregator": "Error",
        "Host.Results": "Information",
        "Function.Function1": "Information",
        "Function.Function1.User": "Error"
      },
      "applicationInsights": {
        "samplingSettings": {
          "isEnabled": true,
          "maxTelemetryItemsPerSecond": 1,
          "excludedTypes": "Exception"
        }
      }
  }
}
```

You can aso change all the ***log levels*** to ***Warning*** or ***Error***.

**Response:**

[image]

[image]

As per [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.applicationinsights.datacontracts.severitylevel?view=azure-dotnet#fields), when the `SeverityLevel=1`, it refers to `Information`. So it displays all the function related information.

Comment: Thanks @pravallika-kv. This has reduced the log statements to only two items:

- Executing 'Functions.abc' ...
- Executed 'Functions.abc' ...

But now I don't see any log statements from my application. In essence I am interested in getting logs from my function + having ability to check function execution time. Nothing more.